# Peek MSMQ message with unlimited timeout

Tags: c#, msmq, timespan, peekmessage

I am writing an application that peeks message from Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ). I want my application peeks MSMQ messages in turn(from the first message to the last message ). After peeks the last message completly, the main thread will be blocked until MSMQ have a new message arrive.
I've already used *MessageQueue.Peek(TimeSpan, Cursor, PeekAction)*  Method with **TimeSpan=MessageQueue.InfiniteTimeout** and have a problem: MessageQueue.InfiniteTimeout value approximates 49 days but I want my app will wait for new message with a very very long time (about 1000 days), I've already switched TimeSpan = TimeSpan.MaxValue but have no success. Could you give me some solutions or advices? thanks!
My code like this:

```js
while (true) {
  if (isTheFirst) {
    try {
      ret = mq.Peek(MessageQueue.InfiniteTimeout, cursor, PeekAction.Current);
      Console.WriteLine(ret.Id);
      isTheFirst = false;
    } catch (MessageQueueException e) {
      // what can we do?
    }
  } else {
    try {
      // because MessageQueue.InfiniteTimeout value approximate 49 days, so if 
      // during 49 days, Message Queue didn't receive any message, my app will 
      // thrown exception but i want my app to continue wait for new message arrive
      ret = mq.Peek(MessageQueue.InfiniteTimeout, cursor, PeekAction.Next);
      Console.WriteLine(ret.Id);
    } catch (MessageQueueException ex) {
      // what can we do?
    }
  }
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: How about simply retrying on timeout?

Comment: Can you explain for me how to retry on timeout? I really don't know how to do. If you can help me, please writing on answer section. thank you!

Comment: See Thomas Jaskula's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to catch the specific error, log it and the loop will continue to Peek the next message.

```
while (true) {
  if (isTheFirst) {
    //... omitted for brievety
  } else {
    try {
      ret = mq.Peek(MessageQueue.InfiniteTimeout, cursor, PeekAction.Next);
      Console.WriteLine(ret.Id);
    } catch (MessageQueueException e) {
      if(e.MessageQueueErrorCode == MessageQueueErrorCode.IOTimeout)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Log here that Timeout has occured");
          continue; // will skip Thread.Sleep(1000); and whatever code you put after
      }
      else
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Log exception and rethrow");
         throw;
      }
    }
  }
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

I don't know you specific use case but waiting so long time for a message on the queue is not usual.

Comment: My app will support another application. Example, if that application have another problem that it can not resolve, it will send message to the MSMQ and then my app will **peek()** that message and help it to execute work, so my app will wait for MSMQ message continuously and for very long time.

Comment: Does my answer helps you with doing it ?

Comment: In the previous question  [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29117142/peek-msmq-message-with-infinite-timeout/29119493?noredirect=1#comment46622640_29119493), you've already helped me so much. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Just don't hesitate to upvote and close if it solves your problem.